# D3js - How to integrate mini libraries like d3-scale in Angular CLI?

Tags: d3.js, angular, angular-cli

I am using d3js for my project in Angular CLI.
I have successfully integrated d3js in the project. In order to perform what I want to create, I need the scale method. However, D3js 4.0 have been split into mini-libraries and it seems like each of them have to be integrated separately into the project. Here you can see the result of *npm install d3*:

[node_module_tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzl7t.png)

I tried importing d3 and d3-scale like this:

*angular-cli-build.js*

```
vendorNpmFiles: [
  'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
  'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
  'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
  'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
  'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
  '@angular2-material/**/*',
  'bootstrap/**/*',
  'ng2-bootstrap/**/*.js',
  'moment/moment.js',
  'd3/**/*.js',
  'd3-scale/**/*.js'
]
```

*system-config.ts*

```
const map: any = {
 '@angular2-material': 'vendor/@angular2-material',
 'ng2-bootstrap': 'vendor/ng2-bootstrap',
 'moment': 'vendor/moment/moment.js',
 'd3': 'vendor/d3/build/d3.js',
 'd3-scale': 'vendor/d3-scale/build/d3-scale.js'
};
```

*my_component*

```
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import * as d3Scale from 'd3-scale';
```

But the build fail even if my d3-scale is in the vendor folder, he cannot find it.

Is it the correct way to integrate those mini libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to run your d3 code ? I mean can you comment out your `import * as d3Scale from 'd3-scale';` and check if the error is still there for d3 ?

Answer (score 1):

I found my problem.
Definitely Typed does not provide a typings file for d3js 4.0 but for 3.0 versions.

That's why I had:
- a method d3.scale.linear() available which returned undefined (typings for d3 3.0)
- the library d3-scale for d3 4.0 which crashed during build

So I will go back to d3js 3.0 until they provide a d.ts file for the 4.0.